# Run a JUnit test from an Eclipse Plugin and accessing the result

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to create a Plugin for Eclipse.
What I want to do is access a JUnit test from the workspace and run it through the plugin.
So far, I've managed to run it using an ILaunchConfiguration, but I don't know how to gather the results of the run.
Since I'd like to run the same test multiple times with small changes in between, I was wondering if there is another way to run the test and easily gathering the result through a plugin?

So far, I've tried using:

```
IProject project = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProjects()[0];
```

For getting a project from the workspace. However, I ran into the problem of being able to run it as a JUnit test.

The way I managed to run the tests were by using

```
ILaunchConfiguration configuration = DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager().getLaunchConfigurations()[1];
```

and then running it by calling

```
configuration.launch(ILaunchManager.RUN_MODE, null);
```

Although I never managed to gather the results

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We would find it helpful if you could provide some information about what you have already tried. Please edit your question to include this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to register an `org.eclipse.jdt.junit.TestRunListener`. You can do this by using the `org.eclipse.jdt.junit.testRunListeners` extension point to register your own TestRunListener class.

Your TestRunListener listens to events which include the JUnit session ending, which is where you will be able to save a reference to that session.

```java
class MyTestRunListener extends TestRunListener {

    public void sessionFinished(ITestRunSession session) {

        // Do something with session - save it away to a collection, for example.

    }




}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am trying this, but I keep getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException whenever I call the class

Comment: Could you make it clearer as to what you're trying to call, and what the ClassNotFoundException is failing to find?

Comment: I tried creating an instance of MyTestRunListener in the same class that launches the ILaunchConfiguration. The ClassNotFoundException is referring to org.eclipse.jdt.junit.TestRunListener

Comment: You don't need to create any instances of MyTestRunListener - if you have registered MyTestRunListener as an org.eclipse.jdt.junit.testRunListeners in your plugin.xml, the Eclipse extension framework will create it and register it for you.

Alternatively, if you want to create and register your own programmatically, then you can call JUnitCore.addTestRunListener(TestRunListener).

For either of these, you will need to make sure that you add org.eclipse.jdt.junit to the required bundles for your plug-in.